Why does this arc die in the center?
I discharged a capacitor across the primary of an old microwave oven transformer. As expected, the transformer made a huge spark. I am generating the spark by charging a capacitor with a bug zapper to ~2kV and then moving it to the transformer and discharging it.

After filming it slow motion, I made two discoveries.

My multimeter spontaneously turns on when I discharge the capacitor

And more interestingly

The spark seems to die in the center like this


Even after multiple trials, the spark always seems to end in the center. Why does the spark always die in the middle?
EDIT
Here's a schematic of what I have to figure out why my circuit is emitting RF:

UPDATE
After reading through all the answers and comments and doing my own calculations, I have been sufficiently terrified into never trying this again. Whatever you do, DO NOT try this, as this was a pretty reckless idea anyway.

Rando, I look forward to seeing your exploits on the Darwin Awards website.

Assuming the capacitor is polarized, the circuit is likely to ring and apply reverse polarity to the capacitor.  You don't mention the type, capacitance or voltage rating of the capacitor.  It may go bang, or vent electrolyte (brief conduction to your fingers seems possible).  The case insulation may be inadequate (less brief conduction).  Consider where your fingers are, with respect to the high voltage and potential shrapnel.  Were you counting on using your fingers, later in life?

please work on personal safety.. Your setup looks magnitudes too unsafe for anyone's sanity.

Arcs usually extinguish in the center as the current dies, if you are ionizing metal or evaporating material, it's likely that there is more of it in the ends and more ions. Regular air has less ions so there is less plasma in the middle.
You are probably sending out some serious RF if you are turning on nearby devices, I would not recommend doing this experiment in the vicinity of electronics or at all.
Edit:
You are essentially making a spark gap transmitter.

Good to know; I could imagine the capacitor and the primary forming an LC tank and creating oscillations. But wouldn't that be contained within the transformer's core? Or does the arc act like a sort of spark gap transmitter?

Not sure, post a schematic of your circuit and we could further answer your question

I hope you know that the crocodile clips you're using have insulation that is quite conductive and will not withstand 2kV. It has trouble withstanding 500V DC, and if it has been handled a lot with sweaty hands, it gets even worse.
You need to be using wires and terminals rated for the 2kV voltage. You'll quickly discover that they are not cheap unless you're reusing anode wires from old CRTs, and even then you'd still need a connector or a switch that can withstand 2kV.
Right now you're on the way to getting injured. Everything in your photographs screams "stop!", especially if you get the natural idea that perhaps a larger primary capacitor would make a stronger spark. Do not do this unless you are very familiar with electrical safety at the voltages and energies you'd be playing with.

I am generating the spark by charging a capacitor

How much energy are you storing in that capacitor (in Joules)?

"The most dealy project on the Internet" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBeSKL9zVro

You have an equivalent circuit like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
At first (before breakdown), the spark gap is open-circuit and secondary capacitance dominates the ring-up; eventually it breaks down, voltage drop is low (as shown; practically a short circuit), and the primary discharges through transformer leakage inductance and resistance.
The arc, might persist due to luminous material caught up in it -- carbon and sodium are likely candidates.  Or I wonder if the radiant heat was enough to flash vaporize some of the nearby dielectric (usually something like fiberglass paper soaked with varnish), it might be a wisp of flame just behind the arc.
You don't show the length of wires left and right of the transformer, but it seems likely they're more than the minimum length to connect things up.  Wire length matters because sparks can happen very, very quickly: in particular, sparks in air can switch in a fraction of a nanosecond!  The resulting change in voltage (on the wires, and in the space surrounding them) happens so quickly that, at first just some 10s of cm drops from high voltage to low, then further out as time goes on, at light speed more or less, propagating out from the spark and up along the wires.  The resulting electromagnetic pulse (EMP) can damage microelectronics -- these are ESD voltages we're talking here -- though the currents with the capacitive discharge are much higher, so the induced currents can be higher.
The secondary side spark should be pretty slow compared to the primary, because the transformer does not respond instantly (actually, MOTs are of a design with quite poor bandwidth, and the secondary rise time will be in the 100s µs).  There will be a two-pulse response where the primary sparks, a time delay, then the secondary sparks.
What effect these pulses have on nearby equipment, who knows.  Randomly pressing buttons, or corrupting data, is a definite possibility, and it seems this was enough stimulus for your meter to wake up.
